# In the VS.NET 2010 IDE am I using tabs or spaces based on default configuration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

This is **not** a question about which is better 'tabs vs spaces'. However I am confused on which method I am actually using. In the default C# VS.NET 2010 IDE 'Tabs' settings it shows a tab size of **4** and the option of **Insert spaces** selected.

OK so *in* the almighty debate and to clear up what VS.NET is using, I press *Tab* on the keyboard but spaces are inserted. Does this mean I am using Tabs or Spaces? It's like I am using 'Tabs' masqueraded as spaces. Which is VS.NET and I using by default and which side of that would I be considered on when using the default options: tabs or spaces?

Please let me know so I can know definitively which method I am using. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for what VS is using, it depends on whether you've selected **Insert spaces** or **Keep tabs** as shown in the screenshot. With **Insert spaces** selected, you'd be considered to be on the spaces side of the debate, as spaces are saved to the actual file.

[image]

Comment: So it boils down to not so much which 'button' I press on the keyboard, but rather which thing: "tabs" or "spaces" is *actually* being used and saved to the file, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You'd be using spaces.  When you hit the tab button, Visual Studio is entering in 4 space characters instead of a tab character.  If you selected 'Keep tabs' in the Tab section of the options, you'd be entering a tab character for every tab button press.